# Node TypeScript import/export mechanics

Tags: node.js, typescript, import, webstorm

I have a problem with TypeScript import/export mechanics in WebStorm.
Lets say, I have a following file, named `apiUtils.ts`:

```
export function getUsername(req) {
    return req.headers.username;
}

export default module.exports;
```

And I have another file, that is referencing apiUtils.ts:

```
import apiUtils from "../bin/apiUtils";

const req = '';
const username = apiUtils.getUsername(req);
```

`getUsername` method is not identified on the fly and I cannot navigate to it with <kbd>Ctrl + click</kbd>. It is marked as unused, and I can even write the following and compile the code successfully without receiving an error:

```
import apiUtils from "../bin/apiUtils";

const req = '';
const username = apiUtils.getUsername(req, thereIsNoSecontArgInThisMehod);
```

On the other hand, if I import the method as follows:

```
import { getUsername } from "../bin/apiUtils";

const req = '';
const username = getUsername(req);
```

And everything will work as expected: I get navigation, input validation and etc.

I prefer to use `import apiUtils from "../bin/apiUtils";` instead of importing each method separately, since it creates a chaos of methods, that is unclear where they belong to, if they are local or not.

Is there a way to fix the import, and get it to understand what method is referenced? Since for the runtime both ways are working the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because of `export default module.exports` construction - none of the IDEs I'm aware of can handle them.

[image]

If you like to import the entire module, use `import * as <name>` construction (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#import-the-entire-module-into-a-single-variable-and-use-it-to-access-the-module-exports):

```
export function getUsername(req) {
    return req.headers.username;
}
```

```
import * as apiUtils from "../bin/apiUtils";

const req = '';
const username = apiUtils.getUsername(req);
```